# merging two data sets in SAS SQL where columns are slightly different

Tags: sas

I am merging two data sets using PROC SQL where the common column is name. However, one dataset has their first initial last name (for example John Smith would be jsmith) and the other is jsmithH. This H is at the end of each name in the second dataset. How can I merge these two data sets together? I think I need to use some sort of similarity between the two but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sql;
create table result as 
select <what ever you want>
from first_table as t1, second_table as t2
where t2.name = compress(t1.name ||'H');
quit;
```

Comment: As I thought was self explanatory: `||` concatenates `t1.name` (including its training blanks) with `"H"` and `compress` removes those blancks